# Regular expression for matching 3 or 4 part expressions with space and colon separators

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to use regex to select expressions that can take the following forms:

```
Name 23:12
```

Or

```
2 Name 122:181
```

It's always the same format:

1. a string, a space, then a number, the colon symbol, then another number, or
2. A single digit `number`, a `space`, a `string`, another `space`, then a `number`, the `colon` symbol, and the last `number`.

Up to now  I was using the following:

```
/(?: |:)+/
```

But of course it does not work for the second scenario.

The regex code is used in a JavaScript bit in Drafts for iOS to manipulate text:

```
var StringSparsed = String.split(/(?: |:)+/);
```

Then, in the `StringSparsed` array resulting from the `split` function, I only want three items:

1. The name (either the first `string` or first `single digit` + `string`)
2. The `number` before the colon symbol
3. The last `number`

I couldn't really figure it out my own. Any idea?

Cheers

Comment: why is it not working, is it not splitting at spaces and colons?

Comment: Yes, I'm really sorry I didn't mention what I was looking for ...  in the array resulting from the split function, I need only three results: the name (either just string or first single number + string), the number before the colon symbol, and the last number...

Comment: please add this to the question itself :)

Comment: btw an edit was made to your question and now the number is missing in the second example

Comment: @inarilo Added to the edit and missing number added back. Sorry for the mess.

Answer (score 0):

You could match the wanted parts and return the rest of the matching parts.

```js
var getParts = s => s.match(/^(.*) (\d+):(\d+)$/).slice(1);

console.log(getParts('Name 23:12'));
console.log(getParts('2 Name 122:181'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Oh I'm sorry i forgot to mention that it needs to give me  A specific results, I will update the original post. Sorry guys

Comment: That looks great but how could I get "2 Name", "122", "181" as a result for the second scenario?

Comment: Well, `.match(/^(.*) (\d+):(\d+)$/).slice(1)` did the trick. Thanks a lot! Sorry I can't upvote your answer, don't have enough reputation 

Answer (score 0):

I am not really a pro but I figured out by using /(?::| :)+/ you skip all blanks and go to the intended result

Answer (score 0):

Use below regex to cover both scenarios:

```
^[0-9]?\s?[a-zA-Z]*\s[0-9]*:[0-9]*$
```

Comment: Hey this works perfect when tested in [regex101](https://regex101.com) but can't make it work in my app with `StringSparsed.split(^[0-9]?\s?[a-zA-Z]*\s[0-9]*:[0-9]*$);`. I guess this is not an issue from your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
/(?:[^\d] |:)/
```

This assumes the string will not end with a digit.

I removed the `+` at the end because it appears only one space or one colon will appear at any position, not "one or more" as indicated by the `+`.

But IMO it would be easier to use a regular expression to get matches instead of using `split()`.

Comment: I understand and guess you're right about doing everything regex, but I'm a beginner at both javascript and regex, so I just found this compromise useful at this point... 

Comment: whatever works :) but regex is quite simple :) just needs a bit of practice

Answer (score 0):

Since all the strings are the same format a good way to split and retrieve them could be the following:

```js
var regex = /(\d+\s)?(\w+)\s(\d+):(\d+)/;
var matches = "1 Name 23:32".match(regex);
console.log(matches);
```

Grouping it this way you'll end up with an array.
At index [0] you'll find the entire match.
At index [1] you'll find a number(if the string starts with one), or an undefined(just the opposite case)
Other index from [2] to [4] will surely contain the "Name" string, digits before the colon and digits after the colon, always in this order.
I'd keep it the more precise i can when using regex, to avoid mismatches.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow that is actually really good and opens new possibilities. Thanks a lot @riot !

Comment: @Manitoba: I'm here to help, glad it did the job. You can find out more on RegExp the MDN js docs if you've never looked at it. The're explaine in a quite good way!